# SOQL Count Distinct Accounts based on MIN Approved Date

Tags: soql

I am trying to create a SOQL query to give me a monthly count of participants based upon the Accounts initial/min approve date.

Here is what I have so far which gives me the correct count by program and by month.  However this does not correctly account for accounts having multiple projects across years.

```
select CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c) CALENDAR_YEAR, CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c) CALENDAR_MONTH,Program_Code__c, COUNT_DISTINCT(Account__c) Participants
from Project__c 
where Project_Status__c = 'Complete'
group by Program_Code__c,CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c), CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c)
ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c),Program_Code__c
```

I was trying to do a SQL subqurey approach but it does not appear that this is supported with SOQL.

```
select CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c) CALENDAR_YEAR, CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c) CALENDAR_MONTH,Program_Code__c, COUNT_DISTINCT(Account__c) Participants
from (
    select MIN(Approve_Date__c),Program_Code__c, Account__c
    from Project__c 
    where Project_Status__c IN ('Payment Approved','Complete')
    group by Program_Code__c, Account__c
    ) 
where Project_Status__c = 'Complete'
group by Program_Code__c,CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c), CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c)
ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c),Program_Code__c
```

Comment: Contradictory and/or unclear statements when taken together: _monthly count of participants_ with _Accounts initial/min approve date_ and _accounts having multiple projects across years_

Comment: An account can participate in the same program multiple times (i.e. multiple projects), however the date of their enrollment should be tied to the month of the first project for the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that **SOQL** does not support subqueries in the FROM clause, unlike **SQL**. However, you can still achieve your desired result by using a different approach.

You can use an aggregate query on the **Account** object and group by the `MIN(Approve_Date__c)` and `Program_Code__c` fields. This will give you the initial approve date and program code for each account.

You can then use another aggregate query on the Project object and join it with the first query using the `AccountId` field. This will give you the monthly count of participants based on the initial approve date and program code.

For example, you can use something like this:

```
// Query the initial approve date and program code for each account
List<AggregateResult> accountResults = [SELECT MIN(Approve_Date__c) initialDate, Program_Code__c programCode, Account__c accountId
                                        FROM Project__c
                                        WHERE Project_Status__c IN ('Payment Approved','Complete')
                                        GROUP BY Account__c, Program_Code__c];

Map<Id, AggregateResult> accountMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
for (AggregateResult ar : accountResults) {
        accountMap.put((Id)ar.get('accountId'), ar);
}

// Query the monthly count of participants based on the initial approve date and program code
List<AggregateResult> projectResults = [SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c) calendarYear, 
                                        CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c) calendarMonth,
                                        COUNT_DISTINCT(Account__c) participants, Account__c accountId
                                        FROM Project__c
                                        WHERE Project_Status__c = 'Complete' AND Account__c IN :accountMap.keySet()
                                        GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c), CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c), Account__c
                                        ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Approve_Date__c), CALENDAR_MONTH(Approve_Date__c), Account__c];

for (AggregateResult ar : projectResults) {
        AggregateResult accountResult = accountMap.get((Id)ar.get('accountId'));
        Date initialDate = (Date)accountResult.get('initialDate');
        String programCode = (String)accountResult.get('programCode');
        Integer calendarYear = (Integer)ar.get('calendarYear');
        Integer calendarMonth = (Integer)ar.get('calendarMonth');
        Integer participants = (Integer)ar.get('participants');
        System.debug('Initial Date: ' + initialDate + ', Program Code: ' + programCode + ', Calendar Year: ' + calendarYear + ', Calendar Month: ' + calendarMonth + ', Participants: ' + participants);
}
```